# about quotient space and linear map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading a book named functional analysis writes  by Peter D Lax

Definition M is a linear map of$$X\rightarrow U,$$ $N_M$ is the set of points mapped int zero.
$R_M$ is the range of M, i.e. is the image of X under M in U.

He wants me to proof M maps the quotient space $X/N_M$ one to one onto $R_M$

Here is my confusion first, I think the element of the quotient space is like $y_1,y_2$ ,such that $y_1-y_2\in N_M$.so M(y_1-y_2)=0,then M(y_1)=M(y_n), but that is contradictory with one-to-one. Where is my error? I don’t know how I made a mistake.

Comment: $y_1$ and $y_2$ represent the same element of quotient space $X/N_M$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have : $X$ and $U$ are vector spaces and $M: X \to U$ is linear.

The quotient map $M_0: X/N_M \to R_M$ is defined by

$$M_0(x+N_M)=M(x).$$

Now let $x+N_M, y+N_M \in X/N_M$ and $M_0(x+N_M)=M_0(y+N_M)$. Then we have $M(x)=M(Y)$, therefore $x-y \in N_M.$ Thus $x+N_M= y+N_M.$

This shows that $M_0$ is injective.

Now it is your turn to show that $M_0$ is onto.

Comment: Thanks a lot .now I proof onto ,let y$\in R_M$,since M is onto ,so there exist $x=M^{-1}(y)$.so $x+N_M$ the inverse     Of y.am I right ?

Comment: Excuse me ..could you please tell me my proof is right or not

Comment: No, your proof is not correct. Let $y \in R_M$. Then there is $x \in X$ with $M(x)=y$. Hence $M_0(x+N_M)=y.$

Comment: that’s what I mean ... my English is poor sorry..